# Retaining columns from both data frames after joining using me

Tags: r

I am merging two data frames using the code snippet below

```
check_store_count<- merge(x = agg_cluster_sku_str_cnt_1, y = agg_cluster_sku_str_cnt_2, by.x = c("cluster_1","sku_1"),
                          by.y = c("cluster_2", "sku_2") , All = TRUE )
```

After merging the above two data frames the resulting file does not have the "cluster_2", "sku_2" fields. How should I get them in the result as well ?

Answer (score 0):

`merge` is designed to work this way. It finds rows where the columns match and creates new rows where they do not. By setting `all = TRUE` you are doing an outer join on the two data frames.

```
df1 <- data.frame(a1 = c(1,2,3),
              b1 = c("a","b","c"),
              c1 = c(4,5,6))


df2 <- data.frame(a2 = c(1,2,4),
              b2 = c("c","b","d"),
              c2 = c(7,8,9))

merge(x = df1,
  y = df2,
  by.x = c("a1", "b1"),
  by.y = c("a2", "b2"),
  all = TRUE)

#   a1 b1 c1 c2
# 1  1  a  4 NA
# 2  1  c NA  7
# 3  2  b  5  8
# 4  3  c  6 NA
# 5  4  d NA  9
```

You could duplicate the columns and leave the duplicates out of the `by` list.

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df2 %>%
  mutate(a2_dup = a2,
         b2_dup = b2)

merge(x = df1,
      y = df2,
      by.x = c("a1", "b1"),
      by.y = c("a2", "b2"),
      all = TRUE)

#   a1 b1 c1 c2 a2_dup b2_dup
# 1  1  a  4 NA     NA   <NA>
# 2  1  c NA  7      1      c
# 3  2  b  5  8      2      b
# 4  3  c  6 NA     NA   <NA>
# 5  4  d NA  9      4      d
```